# Show that the estimator $\hat\lambda_n=\frac{1}{n+a}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is consistent for all $a>0$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent poisson random variables with $\lambda>0$. Show that for any $a>0$ the sequence $(\hat\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is consistent given that: $$\hat\lambda_n=\frac{1}{n+a}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$

**Question:** How do I show this estimator is consistent? Am I on the right track with my apporach?

**My attempt**: I am guessing I am supposed to check if $\hat \lambda_n$ is a consistent estimator for the parameter $\lambda$. First I tried to calculate the expected value:

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split}E[\hat\lambda_n] &= E\left[\frac{1}{n+a}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i
 \right]
\\ &=\frac{1}{n+a} \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]
\\ &=\frac{n}{n+1} \lambda\end{split}\end{equation*}
$$

So for $n\to\infty$ we have: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[\hat \lambda_n]=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1} \lambda= \lambda$$

Therefore this estimator is asymptotically unbiased. I somehow wanted to use this fact to show that it is consistent. In order for the estimator to be consistent, the following must hold:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\Pr(\vert \hat \lambda_n-\lambda \vert \ge \varepsilon)=0$$

I was thinking of using [chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality):

$${\displaystyle \Pr(|X-\mu |\geq \varepsilon )\leq {\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{\varepsilon ^{2}}},} \\ \implies \Pr(\vert \hat{\lambda}_n-\lambda\vert \ge \varepsilon ) \le \frac{\text{Var}(\hat{\lambda}_n)}{\varepsilon^2}$$

However the mean of $\hat \lambda_n$ is only $\lambda$ for $n\to \infty$ (what I showed above) so I am not sure if I can use chebyshev's inequality here. Also I wasn't sure how to get the variance of the sequence. Maybe someone can help me out with this part.

Comment: By the LLN, $\bar X$ (the mean of the sample) converges a.s. to $\lambda.$ Clearly, $\lambda_n = a_n \bar X$ for $a_n \to 1,$ so it also converges a.s. to $\lambda.$ I am not sure if you need a.s. convergence or convergence in L1 or convergence in measure. Note that a.s. convergence implies convergence in measure.

Comment: So I am overcomplicating things with my approach right? I don't see why $$\lambda_n=a_n \bar{X} \hspace{1cm} \text{for} \hspace{1cm} a_n=1 $$ . Could you maybe elaborate. Do I need almost sure convergence for consistency?

Comment: I think consistency means convergence in measure/probability. So, if you prove a.s. convergence, you win. You can write $\lambda_n$ to be a multiple $a_n$ of the sample mean of size $n$ and $a_n = \dfrac{n}{n+a}$ converges to 1. So, if $\bar X \to \lambda$ and $a_n \to 1,$ then $a_n \bar X \to \lambda$ as well.

Comment: Just redo the maths following my comments. Cheers!

Comment: @WillM. Sorry I was looking at the wrong $a_n$. What you wrote makes perfect sense. I posted an answer below. Could you maybe let me know if it's ok. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you another solution.

**Def:** An estimator $T_{n}=g_{n}(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ is consistent for the parameter $\theta$ if $\forall \varepsilon>0:$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\mathbb{P}(|T_{n}-\theta|<\varepsilon)=1$, or equivalently: $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\mathbb{P}(|T_{n}-\theta|\geq\varepsilon)=0$.

**Theorem:** Consider an asymptotically unbiased (for the parameter $\theta$) estimator $T_{n}$ with finite variance $\forall n$. Then if $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}Var(T_{n})=0$ we can conclude that the estimator $T_{n}$ is consistent.

In fact (using the Chebyshev's inequality):
$$0\leq\mathbb{P}(|T_{n}-\theta|\geq\varepsilon)\leq\frac{E(T_{n}-\theta)^2}{\varepsilon^2}=\frac{Var(T_{n})+(E[T_{n}]-\theta)^2}{\varepsilon^2}\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow+\infty}0,$$ since the estimator is asymptotically unbiased and $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}Var(T_{n})=0$.

In your case you've already proved that the estimator is asymptotically unbiased. Let's compute the variance (bearing in mind that the random variables are independent and identically distributed):
$$Var(\hat{\lambda_{n}})=\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(X_{i})=\frac{n\lambda}{(n+a)^2}\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow+\infty}0. $$

We can conclude that the estimator is consistent.

Comment: I like this approach. It basically accomplishes what I wanted to do, namely use the asymptotically unbiased property to show consistency. Thanks!

Comment: @Nullspace Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from Will M.

Rewrite: $$\hat\lambda_n=\frac{1}{n+a}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \iff \hat\lambda_n=\frac{n}{n+a} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=a_n\bar{X}$$

By the WLLN: $$ \hspace{0.5cm} {\displaystyle {\begin{matrix}{}\\{\overline {X}}_{n}\ {\xrightarrow {P}}\ \lambda \qquad {\textrm {when}}\ n\to \infty .\\{}\end{matrix}}} $$

and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1$$

It follows that: $$a_n \bar{X}_n \to\lambda$$

And therefore:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr \left(\vert \hat{\lambda}-\lambda\vert \ge \varepsilon\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr \left(\vert a_n\bar{X}_n-\lambda\vert \ge \varepsilon\right)=0$$

and the estimator is consistent.

Comment: May I ask if this is true for a continuous random sequence? The given sample is poission, which is discrete, but the theory seems to apply in any case.